# GitBucketにアクセスできなくなった

Tags: git, gitbucket

Git push をしようとした時エラーが出てアクセスが出来なくなりました

```
Git: fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://......'
```

試したことは

- URL再登録
- ssh key再登録

webには直接アクセスができます
上記の事を試しても変わらなかったので他は何も思いつきません

Comment: [GitBucket](https://gitbucket.github.io/) は基本的に自分でサーバへのインストールや管理をするもので、ホスティングサービスの [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/) とは異なるものになりますが、お間違えないでしょうか？

Comment: はい間違えてはいません

Comment: httpsでリポジトリにアクセスされているようなので、SSH keyの再登録は残念ながらここでは無駄でしょう。選択肢はおそらくローカルにキャッシュされている認証情報（ID/Passwordなど）を削除するか、remoteのURLをSSHに書き換えることでSSHを使うようにすることでしょうか。（根本的な原因をどうにかするためにも）前者を行うべきでしょうが、環境によって必要な操作が異なります。作業環境のOS，および`git config credential.helper`の出力を教えて下さい。（一応ヘルパーに依存せずに行うことはできますが……）

Comment: @hinaloe ローカルの認証情報を削除し登録しなおしたら上手くいけました

Comment: @hinaloe 出来れば回答を書いて頂けたら嬉しいです

Answer (score 0, accepted):

windowsの資格情報を削除し作成しなおしたらログインできた